# A question on resonance

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, dynamics, vibration

This is to settle a debate.

I was working on a scaffold next to a building, as the wind blew, the scaffolding would sway. As I stood there I was trying to maintain my stability, but my movements seemed to be making the sway of the scaffolding worse.

I thought this was resonance, my brother maintains it is not. If it's not, is there a term for this?

Comment: Ask your brother why they don't think it isn't. If the structure has a frequency at which it resonates and your movement (at that frequency) seemed to make it worse, t looks like resonance.

Comment: Check out Sruton number.

Comment: The problem with this question is that it does not give us any insight what the other possibilities could be. Offcourse resonance exists. But wether your situation is resonanse or not is not determinable by your info alone. So if i were your brother i wouldnt accept any answer as good since theres really nothing other we can answer to that yes resonance could be it.

Comment: Human movement on the floor can induce a vibration in the range of 1 - 4 Hz, with 1.8 - 2.2 Hz being the most likely range for a single person walking. The equation of natural frequency is f = {(k/m)^0.5]/2*pi, in which k is the equivalent spring constant of the structure, m is the mass, so you can calculate the natural frequency of the scaffold to see whether they come close or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any causal system could be represented by a differential equation, which is also uniquely represented in the space of the Fourier spectrum.

Think of the "bode diagram" and a higher magnitude closer to natural frequency. It says that some frequency close to natural will increase proportionally by magnitude on the bode plot. (except if they have **exactly** one phase of 180 °)

[image]

For this example, look at x=0.75 this will mean if a perturbation with 0.75 frequency interact with the system, the system will produce the double magnitud (see x=0.75 and y=2).

Notice at x=1 is the natural frequency, so any input or perturbation even is a very tiny will produce a very very high response on the system.

So yeah, your frequency movement was probably close to the system, **especially** if you tried to counteract the natural movement of the system, as you will actually be in favor of that movement.

When you try to move to the right, you are actually giving the system the oppositive reaction, so you are moving the system to the left ... then, contraintuitively, you must move in favor of the movement so that the reaction force is phased by 180 degrees.

i'm sorry for the skecht:
[image]

But i hope it illustrate what i mean.

In the upper part your head is "balanced" but increasing the energy of the system, the lower you head is moving strongly but contrarest the system movement, so the system decrease energy (if cero would be balanced as static)

Answer (score 1):

The wind was the initial excitation of the scaffold. If it was a gust (not a sustained wind), then the response could be characterized as free vibration with initial conditions (the gust from the wind).

A free vibration is dominated by the natural frequency.

When you were on the scaffold, -my assumption is that- your instinctive motion would be opposite to the sway of the scaffolding. At any case, it would follow the frequency of the scaffold (which is close to the natural frequency). So you were exciting the scaffold with your motion, at a a frequency close to natural frequency.

Resonance occurs close to or at the natural frequency of a structure. So in that respect, I think what you were observing was related to resonance.

Comment: Perhaps reference the Scruton number??

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that your movement could have increased the sway of the scaffolding.

The scaffolding has planks that virtually act as an airfoil and like an airfoil they can experience what is known as divergent flutter. Which is a self-feeding vibration and has caused the total destruction of some of the bridges.

Because of your relatively light mass compared to the scaffolding, your body will move with the frequency of the scaffolding, and your movements will be gradually synchronized and resonate with that of the scaffolding Hence no matter what is your intention your movement will increase sway of the scaffolding.

The military troops don't march on a bridge, just walk, to avoid starting synchronized vibration.

Comment: Its not always marching, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Bridge,_London

Answer (score 0):

There is a name for this phenomenon in the aeronautics world: *pilot-induced oscillation.*  This occurs when the pilot's own response time, error condition measurement and system gain couple to the dynamics of the system and force it into divergent behavior. In short, it means the pilot's control inputs are in phase with the system dynamics, making the error condition worse instead of damping it out.

Comment: Happens a lot in all vehicle accidents